# Query has_many Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a posts model that has many polymorphic attachments. An attachment can be a Text model, Photo model, Question model, or Video model. A post can have multiple attachments so that it can have a text attachment and a photo attachment. My problem arises when trying to retrieve just text and question posts. If I do the following, then it returns all posts with a text attachment, including photo posts. The problem with this is that it returns post with a photo attachment and a text attachment. I want to retrieve posts with just a text attachment or question attachment and no other attachments. How would I go about this?

Here is the query that I currently use:

```
Post.joins(:attachments).where("attachments.media_type IN (:types)", user_id:types:["Text", "Question"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `media_type` is the column which stores the model Class's name, i.e.: `Text`, `Question`, etc. then your code is almost correct, and needs a very small modification to make it work:

```
Post.joins(:attachments).
     where(:attachments => {:media_type => ["Text", "Question"]})
```